# Use the Subsonic.Select() ExecuteTypedList Method with String

Tags: c#, generics, subsonic

This is more a question regarding generics than subsonic:

Imagine if have the following code:

```
    List<int> result = 
      DB.Select(Product.Columns.Id)
        .From<Product>()
        .ExecuteTypedList<int>();
```

That works great and returns a generic list with the ids from my Product table.

But if I want to get a list of the ProductName:

```
    List<String> result = 
      DB.Select(Product.Columns.ProductName)
        .From<Product>()
        .ExecuteTypedList<String>();
```

it throws a compiler message (translated from german):

> "string" has to be a non-abstract type
>   with a public Constructor without
>   parameter, in order to be used as a
>   generic type or in the generic method
>   "SubSonic.SqlQuery.ExecuteTypedList()"
>   as param "T".

cause: String has no empty contructor:

```
int i = new int;       // works
String s = new String; // compiler error: "string" does not contain a constructor that takes '0' argument
```

<strike>If I use a `List<Object>` instead it works</strike>, but is there a more elegant way, where I can use `List<String>` ?

Update: `List<Object>` does not work. I indeed get a list of objects but that seem to be "empty" object that doesn't contain my ProductNames ( object.ToString() returns `{Object}` )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With a little bit dotnet magic it is possible without patching the subsonic code.

1. Create a new class SubsonicSqlQueryExtensionMethods and drop this code:

   ```
   using System;
   using System.Collections.Generic;
   using System.Linq;
   using System.Text;

   using SubSonic;

   namespace MyUtil.ExtensionMethods
   {
       public static class SubSonicSqlQueryExtensionMethods
       {
           public static List<String> ExecuteTypedList(this SqlQuery qry)
           {
               List<String> list = new List<String>();
               foreach (System.Data.DataRow row in qry.ExecuteDataSet().Tables[0].Rows)
               {
                    list.Add((String)row[0]);
               }
               return list;
           }
       }
   }
   ```

Now add a reference to MyUtil.ExtensionMethods to your class:

```
    using MyUtil.ExtensionMethods;
```

And finally this works:

```
    List<String> result = DB.Select(User.Columns.Name).From<User>().ExecuteTypedList();
```

Please note that the above extension method overloads the ExecuteTypedList() method with no type-argument (unfortunately this snippet requires dotnet 3.5, but for me it works)

Answer (score 1):

I know I am late to this party but I found a neat way of 'tricking' this problem.

```
    List<String> result = 
  DB.Select()
    .From<Product>()
    .ExecuteTypedList<String>().Select(p => p.ProductName).ToList<String>();
```

This works like a charm for me.

Hope is helps someone somewhere, As I am sure you are far past the issue.

Comment: That won't work for subsonic 2 since the generic `ExecuteTypedList<T>` method has a `new` constraint, which requires every generic parameter to have an empty constructor (which string hasn't). You probably meant `ExecuteTypedList<Product>()` in your example.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I can think of this, but it is hardly more elegant:

```
List<string>result=DB.Select(Products.Columns.ProductName)
.From<Product>()
.ExecutTypedList<StringBuilder>()
.ConvertAll(sb=>sb.ToString());
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. It would try to match up the resulting columns with properties on StringBuilder.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't look like SubSonic has proper support for ExecuteTypedList with string values. The method that builds the list first looks for a SubSonic type and if there's no match checks to see if T is a value type. Since string isn't a value type it falls through to the last condition which tries to match property names to the column names returned. Since string doesn't have a property name that you can assign, it fails.

See: BuildTypedResult method: http://subsonicproject.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/SubSonic/SqlQuery/SqlQuery.cs

Comment: That's true, but as mentioned above, the main problem is that String has no constructor with 0 arguments, so I even cannot compile my assembly with the above code.

I thought maybe there would be a way to tell the generic method that it should take another contructor instead.

Something like (I know that doesen't work):
.ExecutTypedList<String, where String = new String("")>();


I think I will create a ExecuteTypedStringList() Method to Subsonic.